# Odd behavior on specific computers when cropping with AForge

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image-processing, aforge

I recently built a .NET image processing application using the AForge.NET library.  The program works fine on all of the 10 computers at my place of business where it is installed except for two.  On these two computers, when the user attempts to crop an image, it does not crop at the proper coordinates.  Everything is shifted down and to the right.  The computers are a mix of Windows 7 and Windows 10 computers.  The two computers exhibiting the strange behavior are both Windows 7 computers but it works on the other 5 Windows 7 computers that it is installed on.  I have verified that every computer is running the latest version of the .NET Framework and tested the program on these computers with images acquired from working systems to verify that it isn't a problem with the format of their images.  I am at a loss.  If anyone out there has seen something like this before or has experience with AForge compatibility issues, please let me know.  Thanks in advance!

I don't know how much my source code will help but here is the code for the cropping function.  If additional code from other areas of the application are needed then I can provide them.  Thanks again.

```
private void GetImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int astartatX = (int)initial.X;
            int astartatY = (int)initial.Y;
            int aXdist1 = (int)(Final.X - initial.X);
            int aYdist1 = (int)(Final.Y - initial.Y);
            Crop anewcropper = new Crop(new Rectangle(astartatX * 8 - 125, astartatY * 8 - 125, aXdist1 * 8 + 250, aYdist1 * 8 + 250));
            Bitmap bmpToCrop = (Bitmap)Editor.Image;
            Bitmap anewcroppedImage = anewcropper.Apply(bmpToCrop);
            string processedpath = Path.Combine(pictures, baseprocessedpath);
            string newbaseFilename = Path.Combine(processedpath, "comic.jpg");
            string anewFilename = newbaseFilename.Insert(newbaseFilename.Length - 4, number.ToString());
            bmpToCrop.Dispose();
            anewcroppedImage.Save(anewFilename);
            Editor.Image = anewcroppedImage;
            Editor.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        }
```

Comment: Hard to tell with the info given. Are the 2 computers set to a different DPI and/or Scaling? Different desktop resolutions? Are you stretching the source bitmap to fill the screen before cropping?

Comment: ::Facepalm::  You're right.  It was scaling...  Someone changed the display settings on those two computers without letting me know.  Sorry for the silly question.